# New gorm.xsd location for grails 2x

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Who could help me to find new `gorm.xsd` location for grails 2x?

Old one `http://grails.org/schema/gorm/gorm.xsd` seems does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `xsd` now comes with `group: 'org.grails', name: 'grails-hibernate' version: 2.2.4`